# Nearby API connection and endpoint lost timeout

Tags: android, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

I'm currently developing an application which uses Google Nearby Connections API. I'm curious whether there is a method to change the timeout for onEndpointLost (method of the EndpointDiscoveryCallback class) and onFailure (method of the OnFailureListener interface).

In my understanding these methods (callbacks) are called when a predefined time is up, and we get these failure calls. I would like to lower this delay, because after a discovered endpoint dissapears, the onEndpointLost method is called too late to my taste. Same applies when a device tries to establish a connection to an endpoint which no longer advertises, resulting in the onFailure callback.

(I would be exxxtra happy if you, Xlythe could spare some time to help me (: )

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to manually adjust these timeouts, and we don't plan to expose a way either. This is because we're combining different scans (eg. BT + BLE + WiFi) and each scan has its own advertising/scanning interval. There isn't a one-size-fits-all number that would work for everything, and we don't control the timeout ourself for every medium (although we do for some).

As for some good news, we are optimizing the onEndpointLost timeout to be shorter for BLE. That's currently our largest timeout (at 15sec) and we're exploring lowering it (to 3sec). This won't lower the overall timeout to 3sec, but it should make it significantly lower.

For the onFailure event, I'd need to know which one you're referring to. If it's a connection request, you can interrupt the request by calling disconnectFromEndpoint. With that, you can have your own timeout of whichever value you want.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it is a connection request. I'll try the method that you suggested.